# using crudrepository with fixed length column in Oracle 11g

Tags: jpa, oracle11g, spring-data, fixed-width, crud-repository

I am trying to write a spring boot that queries a Oracle 11g database.

was a very simple `select * from item where item_code = 'abc'` command.

But because the database uses CHAR(10) for that id column, I found that I can only use like in the where clause. Basically all the derived query of crudRepository failed. I have had to jump hoops to find that only `like` works.

below is what I used in the interface class

```
//itemCode = 'AB1234' in all cases below

public Item findByIdItemCode(String itemCode); //return 0 result

@Query("select r from Item r where r.id.itemCode = 'AB1234'") 
public Item findcustomfix(); //return 1 result

@Query("select r from Item r where r.id.itemCode = :itemCode")
public Item findcustom(@Param("itemCode") String itemCode); //return 0 result

@Query("select r from Item r where r.id.itemCode like %:itemCode%")
public Item findcustomLike(@Param("itemCode") String itemCode); //return 1 result

//application.properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

//class itemKey
@Column(name="ITEM_CODE", columnDefinition="CHAR", length = 10)
//@Column(name="ITEM_CODE", columnDefinition="CHAR(10)") //also does not work
private String itemCode;
```

I have added the length definition but this still seems not enough for hibernate to generate a `where ITEM_CODE = 'AB1234    '` clause that considers the fixed width column

I cannot afford to keep using the `like` approach as it cannot discern between AB123 and AB1234.

Is there a proper way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

log:

```
Hibernate: select i1_0.com, i1_0.item_code from stock i1_0 where i1_0.item_code=?
org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind: binding parameter [1] as [ **VARCHAR** ] - [AB1234]
```

traced the stack that finally this VARCHAR is returned from

org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.VarcharJdbcType.getJdbcTypeCode()
which way up in the stack from JdbcParameterBindings ==> jdbcValueBinder

perhaps I have to force it to find as CHAR instead of VARCHAR? I am still looking for how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tools you use.

In Oracle, `char` datatype does what you experienced: right-pads value with spaces up to max column length. That's OK if you really have such values, for example

- Boolean datatype "simulation" (as at SQL level Oracle doesn't support it) so you'd store Y/N, 0/1 or something like that - that's always CHAR(1)
- social security numbers (or similar), which have fixed length of "n" characters
- and so on

But, for strings whose length varies, `char` is rarely appropriate because ... well, you know why - *issues* while working with them.

Here are some options you might want to consider (strictly Oracle-related).

```
SQL> create table test (val char(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (val) values ('ABC');

1 row created.

SQL> select val, length(val) len from test;

VAL               LEN
---------- ----------
ABC                10
```

Use actual value, right-padded with spaces:

```
SQL> select * from test where val = 'ABC       ';

VAL
----------
ABC
```

Trim it:

```
SQL> select * from test where trim(val) = 'ABC';

VAL
----------
ABC
```

Like it:

```
SQL> select * from test where val like 'ABC%';

VAL
----------
ABC
```

Rpad it:

```
SQL> select * from test where val = rpad('ABC', 10, ' ');

VAL
----------
ABC
```

**However**: if you can afford it, modify column's datatype:

```
SQL> alter table test modify val varchar2(10);

Table altered.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 VAL                                                VARCHAR2(10)
```

Column's value is, though, still 10 characters in length (spaces are kept):

```
SQL> select val, length(val) len from test;

VAL               LEN
---------- ----------
ABC                10
```

Update it:

```
SQL> update test set val = trim(val);

1 row updated.

SQL> select val, length(val) len from test;

VAL               LEN
---------- ----------
ABC                 3
```

Now you don't have to use any other functions or operators to access value *as is*:

```
SQL> select * from test where val = 'ABC';

VAL
----------
ABC
```

Comment: I can't afford to change column type, other applications that run on the same DB are maintained by others. I am using SQL Developer as client to connect to 11g, and I am trying to code in the most recent spring boot version. perhaps taking this to the direction of why jdbc decided to bind to VARCHAR even though columnDefinition suggested CHAR and length was already provided would be more helpful. I understand how fixed length columns work.